# How to manually mirror armature in blender 2.78a?

Tags: armature

In all previous version, we used to mirror armature by copying one side, and then center 3D cursor to zero, and duplicate, and scale by -1. However I notice that in version 2.78, (correct me if I'm wrong) scaling -1 on x seems to work differently than before as it will caused unwanted rotation on bones. Is it happening to everyone else, and what do I do to prevent it?
[image]

Comment: Nevermind, I tried in 2.77, it still happens.

Comment: Yea, it's long lasting inconvenience in Blender, but it's easy to fix with pressing W and choosing Symmetrize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mzidare said, you can try Symmetrize. Here's a mirroring technique that circumvents this problem: 
You can enable **X-Mirror**, then extend from a central bone with **E**. The extension should occur symmetrically, and any changes to one should affect the other. I hope this helped :)